# jupyter notebook - change kernels isn't working

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have multiple kernels in my notebook, but when changing the kernel it doesn't really change it and still run the original kernel (which I first open the notebook with).

For example, I run the notebook with python 3.6 environment, but when changing the kernel to python 2.7 it stayed with python 3.6.

I'm changing the kernels via jupyter GUI (kernel -> change kernel) and check the path of python using:

```
!which python
```

In all environments I installed *ipykernel* but it doesn't matter which kernel I'm choosing, the path stayed the same (the path of the original kernel which I used to run the notebook).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, launching jupyter from the terminal after activating the environment worked for me, I followed the steps as below:

1. Open anaconda prompt
2. Activate environment with `conda activate EnvName`
3. Launch jupyter with `jupyter lab`

Comment: Note: Jupyter Notebook and Jupyter Lab are different products. And the initial request was about switching a kernel in a running Jupyter Notebook.